# Does not output to the image file

Tags: php, image, hex, pi

I have this **PHP** program from http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/#files. The program is supposed to convert the numbers of **pi** into individual colors (One number per pixel) and save it to an **image** file like this image: http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/Pi1024x768.gif. But the output of my code is **Binary** in the debugging console. Kinda like this:

```
¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯
```

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
//Title:
//  Pi Graphical Visualization Script
//Date:
//  03.14.07
//Author:
//  Tim Habersack
//Descript: 
//  Reads in the digits of pi, assigns a color to each number 0-9, 
//  then outputs to an image with one pixel representing a number.
//Notes:
//  (http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/pi) is where I obtained the pi file, 
//  calculated to over 4 million decimal places.  The GD library
//  in your php config must be enabled for this to function.
//E-mail:
//  tim@hithlonde.com
//Copyright:
//  Released under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 License

function NumToColor($ImagePassed, $NumPassed)
{
    $the0 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $the1 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $the2 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
    $the3 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
    $the4 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);
    $the5 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00);
    $the6 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    $the7 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
    $the8 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80);
    $the9 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

    switch ($NumPassed)
    {
    case 0:
        return $the0;
        break;
    case 1:
        return $the1;
        break;
    case 2:
        return $the2;
        break;
    case 3:
        return $the3;
        break;
    case 4:
        return $the4;
        break;
    case 5:
        return $the5;
        break;
    case 6:
        return $the6;
        break;
    case 7:
        return $the7;
        break;
    case 8:
        return $the8;
        break;
    case 9:
        return $the9;
        break;
    }   
}

//Set the size of the pi image
$x = 300;
$y = 300;

$gd = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

//Connect the pi file to variable 
$theTestPi = file_get_contents("pi.txt");

$theGoodPi = "";

$PiWalker = 0;

//gets the # of digits needed, plus some extra for the \r dropped off, reads into var

while ($PiWalker < $x * $y * 1.1)
{
    if ($theTestPi[$PiWalker] == "\r")
    {   
        $PiWalker++;
    }
    else
    {
        $theGoodPi = $theGoodPi . $theTestPi[$PiWalker];
    }
    $PiWalker++;    
}

$PiWalker = 0;

//walks through the image, painting the pi characters pixel by pixel
for ($theY = 0; $theY < $y; $theY++)
{
    for ($theX = 0; $theX < $x; $theX++)
    {
        imagesetpixel($gd, $theX, $theY, NumToColor($gd, $theGoodPi[$PiWalker]));
        $PiWalker++;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($gd);

?>
```

I am using **Netbeans** IDE **8.0** **Xampp compiler** version **1.8.3-4** (**PHP** version **5.5.11**).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove the single white space before the opening php tag.
2) There is no need to create "$theGoodPi", just use theTestPi, its just copying it anyway. It makes it take longer for nothing.
3)$theTestPi = file_get_contents("http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/pi");
You may not need to change 3
4)imagesetpixel($gd, $theX, $theY, NumToColor($gd, $theTestPi[$PiWalker]));
Change to theTestPi if you remove the while loop above (see 2)

***All you really need to do is remove the single white space before the opening php tag though lol.***

Comment: Did it not work after you removed the single space? Im at a different pc, I dont have the code right now. Ill check later.

Comment: what compiler are u using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Title:
//  Pi Graphical Visualization Script
//Date:
//  03.14.07
//Author:
//  Tim Habersack
//Descript: 
//  Reads in the digits of pi, assigns a color to each number 0-9, 
//  then outputs to an image with one pixel representing a number.
//Notes:
//  (http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/pi) is where I obtained the pi file, 
//  calculated to over 4 million decimal places.  The GD library
//  in your php config must be enabled for this to function.
//E-mail:
//  tim@hithlonde.com
//Copyright:
//  Released under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 License

function NumToColor($ImagePassed, $NumPassed)
{
    $the0 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $the1 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $the2 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
    $the3 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
    $the4 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);
    $the5 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00);
    $the6 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    $the7 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
    $the8 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80);
    $the9 = imagecolorallocate($ImagePassed, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

    switch ($NumPassed)
    {
    case 0:
        return $the0;
        break;
    case 1:
        return $the1;
        break;
    case 2:
        return $the2;
        break;
    case 3:
        return $the3;
        break;
    case 4:
        return $the4;
        break;
    case 5:
        return $the5;
        break;
    case 6:
        return $the6;
        break;
    case 7:
        return $the7;
        break;
    case 8:
        return $the8;
        break;
    case 9:
        return $the9;
        break;
    }   
}

//Set the size of the pi image
$x = 300;
$y = 300;

$gd = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

//Connect the pi file to variable 
$theTestPi = file_get_contents("http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/pi");

$theGoodPi = "";

$PiWalker = 0;

//gets the # of digits needed, plus some extra for the \r dropped off, reads into var

while ($PiWalker < $x * $y * 1.1)
{
    if ($theTestPi[$PiWalker] == "\r")
    {   
        $PiWalker++;
    }
    else
    {
        $theGoodPi = $theGoodPi . $theTestPi[$PiWalker];
    }
    $PiWalker++;    
}

$PiWalker = 0;

//walks through the image, painting the pi characters pixel by pixel
for ($theY = 0; $theY < $y; $theY++)
{
    for ($theX = 0; $theX < $x; $theX++)
    {
        imagesetpixel($gd, $theX, $theY, NumToColor($gd, $theGoodPi[$PiWalker]));
        $PiWalker++;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($gd); 

?>
```

Comment: gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 0       Will this enable GD?, I removed the semicolon.

Comment: I think i have GD enabled

Comment: No. The error, which I cant copy paste, its an image... Is that its looking for a file with a blank name.

Comment: [http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/pi](http://www.hithlonde.com/pi/pi) heres pi.txt if thats what you need

Comment: what can't be viewed?

Comment: OK, Im at where you are now. Its showing binary(Hexadecimal is 0-9 and A-F, 16 possible numbers) Im seeing the funny characters too. Should be fixable. Gimme a sec.

Comment: you just needed to remove the single white space at the beginning of the file. I changed the answer.

Comment: Also, I had said earlier, that hexadecimal was the wrong term for the symbols were were seeing. That is correct, but I do not think they are binary as I had said. Im not sure what that gobbeldy gook is to be honest.